# ¿como configuro CORS en Laravel 9 para producción en windows + REACT JS?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, apache, xampp, cors

llevo días buscando respuesta o solución pero nada me funciona.
Tengo un Back-end en **LARAVEL 9** desplegado con apache de XAMPP y mi front-end esta en **REACT** alojado en el IIS de win srver.

La aplicación es un gestor de clientes y equipos.

En modo de prueba con Laravel en el puerto:8000 funciona bastante bien, las consultas las hace sin problema, pero cuando hago la consulta ya al servidor de aparache ( C:my-app/public/api/) me manda error por permisos del **CORS**.  Lo raro de esto es que me deja ver información y creación de usuarios y de clientes, pero al hacer un get para las sucursales de un cliente me manda esto-->

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la configuracion que tengo en config/cors.php es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y las reglas que le puse en middleware

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En laravel 9 no necesitas un middleware para cors. En las versiones anteriores a la v7 tenías que instalar un paquete para cors,crear un middleware y aplicarlo a las rutas.
Si estás usando un middleware relacionado con cors quítalo. En tu archivo de config/cors.php `'allowed_origins' => ['http://www.url-app-react.com','http://url-app-react.com']`.
luego ejecuta el comando
`php artisan config:cache`
En tu navegador, presiona CTRL+SHIFT+R recargar caché.

Espero te ayude

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y no lo puedo solucionar con eso. Estoy usando laravel 10